# How to save Strings locally and then update them programmatically?

Tags: java, android

what is the best way to store some Strings(used in Textview as a text) locally and then update them programmatically? Because I think(researched) that data can not be changed during runtime from **res/values/Strings.xml**

for example, I have a **Textview**, **EditText**, and a **button**. I get TextValue from **Strings.xml** using SetText in JAVA. I want to change the single string value from Strings.xml the value that I get from EditText.

Tell me some alternative method to get and change strings value or to how to use custom strings.xml to change the value in runtime.

Comment: You cannot change the values that is present in strings.xml. If you want your string to change I would suggest you use SharedPreferences or Database whatever suits your use case

Comment: if you want to save strings, you should to use something like SharedPreferences, or File, or Database or cloud, you can not update resource values at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Values places in XML are immutable, so you cannot change them at runtime. If you want changed values then set them directly on TextView by adding TextWatcher to your Edittext or setValues from a button's click listener.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the name, this is what [`SharedPreferences`](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) are there for.